# Mindset to understand category theory

Tags: ct.category-theory, learning-roadmap

I am a 17 years old student and I am really interested in category theory due to its abstraction and beauty. I wanted to know if you'd have any advices to approach this theory and if you have papers to begin with this.

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: This question is likely to be closed as not a good fit for the site. With that said, and with the proviso that I am not at all a category theorist or even close to one, one piece of advice might be: learn some of the math that motivated the introduction of categories (e.g. algebraic topology/geometry). Emily Riehl once pithily described category theory as "the mathematics of mathematics"- it seeks to recognize patterns common to many mathematical contexts. Studying category theory before other math would be like studying abstract theories of sociology without having experienced any cultures.

Comment: I see what you are saying, thank you for answering this , I take note of what you said :)

Comment: I would say (and this may be an unpopular opinion) that studying some elementary set theory helps prepare you for a categorical mindset; it familiarizes one with the idea of a 'primitive notion' in the form of sets, and gives you some examples of things to build categories from (including the category of sets, which takes on more life when you've studied elementary set theory and realize it can change under different axiomatizations etc.). Moving to a categorical mindset still requires some work, replacing the primitive of 'set' with two primitives of 'object' and 'arrow', but it helped me.

Comment: Also, elementary set theory as taught in e.g. [Monk's book](http://euclid.colorado.edu/~monkd/monk11.pdf) is a good deal more abstract than undergraduate mathematics usually is, and is a good first step-up in abstraction towards category theory.

Comment: A basic course in Algebraic Topology is probably the fastest and least painful way to see some elementary category theory and the power of functoriality in action. But it still requires a bit of experience/background in both general topology and basic algebra - after all, you'd be interested in functors from topological spaces into collections of algebraic objects (groups, rings). A course in multivariable analysis would definitely be helpful. So, I guess the main question is what background do you already have? Only then we can give you a reasonable answer, e.g. a roadmap, to Category Theory.

Comment: I think this is a good question. The evolved culture at MO suggests to me that this question should be Community Wiki. (I would not expect a new user to be aware of such conventions.) This (nonobvious) convention is consistent with getting answers in the comments, including from me.

Comment: I recommend allowing yourself to learn category theory nonlinearly and from many sources simultaneously. One place to start, albeit a bit dated now, are This Week’s Finds https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.04168. YouTube has lots of “intro to category theory” lectures, but I cannot find the original. (I think Eugenia Cheng was one of the members of the first group to put category theory lectures on YouTube. In any case, she is awesome and you should look up her videos.)

Comment: I also think that, when you will go to college, many of your professors will be happy to say things in categorical language if you ask them to, but might not if you do not ask. If you are 17, you might also be eligible for one of the many math summer camps, and you might find category theorists among the instructors. For instance, I know Mike Shulman and Claudia Scheimbauer have both worked as math camp counsellors (at different math camps).

Comment: In the meantime, here is an exercise. Learn what is a “universal property”. Then for every mathematical definition or construction that you encounter, see if you can construct a notion of “morphism” for which that definition realizes a universal property. You will fail for some definitions, but you will succeed for many.

Comment: You might benefit from checking out the books *Sets for mathematics* by Lawvere and Rosebrugh, and *Conceptual mathematics* by Lawvere and Schanuel.

Comment: I vote _against_ closing.  While the question may appear to be superficially unsuitable, ask yourself the following question: where else one could ask the same question and hope to get nontrivial answers from professional mathematicians?  MSE will not work, and I do not know of any other resources with remotely comparable audience.

Comment: As someone who got interested in category theory before learning much “serious” mathematics I echo Mike’s recommendation of _Sets for mathematics_. Awodey’s _Category theory_ is also good. But I think you have to learn “ordinary” mathematics alongside in order to really appreciate category theory.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov: Dmitri, why is MSE deemed unsuitable for such a question? I thought it would be exactly the place for such questions. I agree though that MO is in all likelihood the best place to obtain such an advice. OTOH, several MO users frequent MSE as well.

Comment: @M.G.: MSE has fewer experienced users of category theory and way more inexperienced ones.  Hence, it has much lower quality of answers.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Nothing prevents you from answering questions about category theory on MSE.

Comment: You can find various lecture notes and books on category theory [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370/good-books-and-lecture-notes-about-category-theory). You can also find resources for learning other areas of math (topology and algebra) from a categorical perspective [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716878/categorical-introduction-to-algebra-and-topology).

Comment: It is relevant that Matias is 17 because that presumably means he hasn't started a university course. Assuming that he intends to study mathematics (rather than, say, computer science) it is probably better to follow the usual topics (group theory, topology, linear algebra, etc) first, and thereby see how category theory organises them, as in @EmilyRiehl's "mathematics of mathematics". If you can do that knowing that category theory is in the background, so much better than being presented with a disorganised undergraduate syllabus and then having to sort it out as a grad student.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: The enormous number of questions, even when restricted to the relevant tags, is a serious obstacle, a lot of people simply do not have time to sift through them.  Additionally, due to the huge number of questions, individual answers tend to get buried and have less impact than here.

Comment: @einzwein: “People of any age can learn math”: so an 8-year old would have no problem mastering the geometric Langlands program, for example?  The work of Jean Piaget and others shows that there are limitations on what one can learn at a given age.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov This is a common false argument that gets often used to justify off-topic questions: "There isn't another suitable SE site for this question, so it must be on-topic here". Just no. Stack Exchange isn't supposed to cover every possible question.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: No, that was not what I said.  This question really does require the expertise of professional mathematicians, and for that reason cannot be moved to MSE or another similar site.  The [textbook-recommendation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/textbook-recommendation?tab=Votes) tag clearly demonstrates that the question is on-topic.  Learning category theory presents its own rather unique challenges that are not at all obvious to an outsider.  This situation is quite different from that of numerical linear algebra and matrix equations, say.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Yes, but is this question about research mathematics? "This is a question that only professional mathematicians can answer, so it must be on-topic here" is *another* fallacy that is often used as an argument, for instance for questions on history of science that are not research mathematics, or to advertise products targeted at mathematicians.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Yes, because category theory is crucial for many branches of modern research mathematics and is part of modern research mathematics itself.  The MathOverflow community agrees with this sentiment: out of the 150 most voted for questions in the [textbook-recommendation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/textbook-recommendation?tab=Votes) tag, only 1 question (about a specific publisher) is closed, and some of these questions involve topics that are far more elementary: linear algebra, ODEs, measure theory, introductory real analysis, combinatorics.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Selection bias: it's not surprising that out of the most voted questions few are closed, and keep in mind that some closed questions are deleted automatically, so you won't see them in searches.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: No, this is blatantly false.  For example, for the [soft-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/soft-question?tab=votes) tag, 22 out of the top 150 questions are closed.  That only 1 out of the top 150 questions for the textbook-recommendation tag is closed is a good indication that the community thinks that such questions are on-topic.  But this discussion is itself now off-topic.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Soft-question is probably the most controversial tag here; I am not surprised it is an outlier and I wouldn't use it as a comparison. Anyhow, this is not the typical textbook-recommendation question; it has an unusual target.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: If you don't like the soft-question tag, take the [mathematics-education](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/mathematics-education?tab=votes) tag: 20 out of the top 150 questions are closed.  The target of this question is the same as for questions about textbooks for [linear algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16994/), [undergraduate ODE](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28721/), [measure theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11591/), [introductory real analysis](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4023/): somebody beginning to study research mathematics.

Comment: Kari Vilonen once pithily remarked that teaching category theory to a first year undergraduate was like giving nuclear weapons to a baby. I don't endorse the view --- but while a baby might well set the world on fire by pure accident, it's not clear that a 1st year undergraduate would have the scope and/or vision to make the earth shake, mathematically speaking. As the comments above make clear, it takes some perspective to be able to do something truly dangerous. I certainly don't mean to discourage your studies --- I only offer the comment as an example of the hot tempers the subject teases.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov math-education is another controversial tag, with many people who think that those questions should be moved to the apposite SE site. Your stat (number of questions that gather many upvotes and close votes at the same time) just measures whether a tag is controversial or not, i.e., if people agree on which questions are good or bad for MO. So "the community thinks that such questions are on-topic" is not a conclusion supported by those numbers. This is a controversial question in a usually non-controversial tag.

Comment: There is the standard and classic text https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categories_for_the_Working_Mathematician, which seems curiously to have not yet been mentioned in the comments or answers

Comment: A guy on the beach watches me surf, and when I come in, he runs up to me and excitedly says, "I want to learn how to surf. Can you help me?" The best response? A) The best surfboards are guns. B) Let's see how well you can swim. C) I recommend this book on the Navier-Stokes equation. D) There's this great Doraemon manga on swimming. (I saw him run in the sand, so I know he has some decent balance and lungs.) // The competence of American high school students in math has an incredibly broad distribution. For the top in the class in Japan, no problem.

Comment: I think to echo what other people said, the teaching of category theory at an early age is somewhat controversial.  I have heard a well-known mathematician working in algebraic geometry say that they do not like to talk about categories in an undergraduate class as they do not wish to corrupt youth, take from that what you will.

Comment: @VivekShende I would say CWM is not appropriate for someone who has not completed some first courses in algebra and topology. At least, that was my experience trying to read it too early.

Comment: A nice thing about books is that you can open them for yourself and find out if they're appropriate for you or not.  A particularly nice thing about CWM is that the first chapter has many examples drawn from algebra and topology so teaches you quite quickly that you may wish to learn these subjects.

Comment: And what about allowing high school students to learn about calculus!?!? Danger! :) :) :)

Comment: I recently learned that category is not just the mathematics of mathematics, but doctrines and 2-categories ( for example ) are the mathematics of mathematics of mathematics. It requires a very good level of abstraction. Needless to say, you need to study mathematics first to understand even what these abstractions are about.

Answer (score 36):

An approach to studying that works with many branches of mathematics is to learn the prerequisites first, then study a good textbook on the subject.
For instance, one could study subjects like algebra, measure theory, smooth manifolds, functional analysis in this manner.

Although a textbook on the subject can include examples from other subjects that one has not studied yet,
the presence of such examples typically does not prevent one from successfully mastering the particular subject under consideration.
(I would say that a good textbook should certainly try to include connections to other areas and not portray its subject as an isolated field.)

For category theory, taking such a route can be quite difficult.
Indeed, the (formal) prerequisites are almost nonexistent: elementary logic and set theory will do.
But such simplicity can be deceiving.

For instance, the notion of a [Kan extension](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kan+extension) can be very puzzling
until one learns a few specific nontrivial examples, such as pushforward and pullback maps for sheaves,
various geometric realization functors, or quantization of Dijkgraaf–Witten theories.

Even the definitions of relatively simple notions, such as [equivalence of categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/equivalence+of+categories)
may convey a rather deceiving picture of their importance,
until one learns some really deep examples of equivalences of categories,
such as the Gelfand duality, Hahn–Banach theorem, spectral theorem for normal operators, Pontrjagin duality, Serre–Swan theorem, GAGA, or second and third Lie theorems.

As may be obvious from the above examples, it may be difficult to present category theory with sufficient
motivation without making considerable use of other areas.
This immediately presents a serious problem: from what areas one should draw examples?
Trying to cover all of mathematics is too hard.
Concentrating on examples from a specific area (e.g., algebra, like some books on category theory do)
immediately creates its own problems: an analyst reading a category theory textbook with examples from algebra
may not see much value in it, since it does not seem to relate directly to analysis.

Thus, one point of view is that the best way to learn category theory is to study other branches of mathematics that actively use categorical concepts.

Here are some textbooks that present their subject using categorical tools where appropriate:

- **Algebra**: Paolo Aluffi.  *Algebra.  Chapter 0*.  Graduate Studies in Mathematics 104 (2009).
- **Algebraic topology**: Tammo tom Dieck.  *Algebraic Topology*.  EMS Textbooks in Mathematics (2008).
- **Functional analysis**: Alexander Helemskii.  *Lectures and Exercises on Functional Analysis*.  Translations of Mathematical Monographs 233 (2006).
- **Elementary set theory**: F. William Lawvere, Robert Rosebrugh.  *Sets for Mathematics*.  Cambridge University Press (2003).
- **General topology**: Tai-Danae Bradley, Tyler Bryson, John Terilla.  *Topology.  A Categorical Approach*.  MIT Press (2020).
- **Elementary topology**: Ronald Brown.  *Topology and Groupoids*.  BookSurge (2006).

Once you are familiar with a few subjects that use category theory,
you may want to solidify your knowledge by studying categories more systematically.
Of the available books, the better one in terms of size and selection of material appears to be

- Emily Riehl.  *[Category Theory in Context](http://math.jhu.edu/%7Eeriehl/context.pdf)*.  Dover (2016).

Comment: I would add: start with Lawvere-Rosebrugh, then proceed to Bradley-Bryson-Terilla and after that you can get into the deep waters of the first three references. Also the videos by the "Catsters" as suggested by @mozibur ullah in another answer should be useful to start.

Comment: These sound reasonable for a strong university student, or a professional mathematician who somehow has missed out on category theory, but how realistic is it to expect a 17 year old student to learn functional analysis from Helemskii and use it a springboard into category theory?

Comment: @MarkWildon: What is it that you find unrealistic here?  I am not suggesting to learn functional analysis without first learning real analysis.  Concerning your comment about age, I started studying functional analysis when I was 18 years old and real analysis when I was 17 years old, so studying real analysis for a year and then moving on to functional analysis worked just fine for me and it can also work for others.

Comment: Definitely going to give a +1 over Paolo Aluffi's book. I was 18 and in my first semester of community college when I picked it up -- it was my first exposure to algebra and category theory and caused me to fall in love with both areas.

Comment: Slightly off-topic: Do you have a reference that discusses quantization of DW theories as a Kan extension?

Comment: @CalvinMcPhail-Snyder: Some references I am aware of (with various degree of explicitness):
Jeffrey C. Morton's [Cohomological Twisting of 2-Linearization and Extended TQFT](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.5603v4)
Section 2 and 3 of Gijs Heuts and Jacob Lurie's [Ambidexterity](http://libgen.rs/book/index.php?md5=EB61F61E995B92E1365EB1C50AC01D1E),
Section 3 of Freed–Hopkins–Lurie–Teleman's [Topological quantum field theories from compact Lie groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0731v2).

Comment: @CalvinMcPhail-Snyder: For the general framework, see:
nLab: [motivic quantization](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/motivic+quantization),
Johan Alm's [Quantization as Kan extension](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/Kantization09May27.pdf),
Section 4.3 in Joost Nuiten's [Cohomological quantization of local prequantum boundary field theory](https://dspace.library.uu.nl/handle/1874/282756),
Sections 4 and 5 of Urs Schreiber's [Quantization via linear homotopy types](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.7041).
Say hi to Kolya from me.

Comment: In which way is Hahn-Banach an equivalence of categories?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: See, for example, pages 15–16 in my [notes](https://dmitripavlov.org/notes/2018s-6325.pdf), pages 23–27 in the [handwritten notes](https://dmitripavlov.org/notes/2018s-6325-handwritten.pdf).  Formulating it in this manner becomes a necessity when working in arbitrary toposes, see Mulvey and Pelletier, _[A globalization of the Hahn–Banach theorem](https://doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(91)90082-i)_.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Your notes are great. Thank you for the link. Great idea to write these notes.

Answer (score 23):

I have an advice: Don't do it. I was once like you, and went into lectures about CT barely knowing any mathematics at all. The result: I didn't understand anything and failed. Learning CT requires a lot of background so that the ideas sound more "natural". If you're asking how to learn CT because of It's "abstraction and beauty", you're probably romanticizing for no good reason.

I am being blunt because that failure almost took my motivation to study any mathematics. That could also happen to you.

Comment: +1: I agree with you simply because there aren't any good books on teaching Category Theory to the informed layman, unlike calyclus, geometry, logic and so on. I think it can actially be made more engaging than it tends to be by tbose fond of abstraction.

Comment: Romanticization is a very big temptation indeed. At least it was for me, and I have seen it in others as well. Very good to warn against this.

Comment: Indeed, some caution is warranted... but/and when to be an aesthetic romantic apart from one's youth? :)  Maybe in retirement? :)

Answer (score 18):

Unfortunately, there aren't many textbooks available to learn Category Theory from for the bright undergraduate or college student, unlike set theory or calculus.

Although, it is characterised as being abstraction heavy, it is no more so than set theory or calculus. Personally, what sold it to me is that category theory showed that the multiplication (product) was dual to addition (coproduct). Another slogan is that set theory emphasises the membership relation, whilst category theory emphasises the functional relation.  The concrete application that showed how it was concretely useful, was to notice that the chain rule in differential calculus in vector spaces generalises to over manifolds and there it is seen as a *functor*.

One textbook is Lawvere & Schanuel's, *Conceptual Mathematics*. This was designed for high-school students.

At a more advanced level, check out Eugenia Chengs online lecture notes on category theory. I can recommend this highly - it's where I learnt category theory from. Eugenia is also known as a presenter of *The Catsters*, a series of short videos on category theory, and available on YouTube, and again, highly recommended.

Answer (score 18):

I think Fong and Spivak's [Seven Sketches in Compositionality](http://math.mit.edu/%7Edspivak/teaching/sp18/7Sketches.pdf) is the ideal answer to this question.  You phrased your question as being about the "mindset" that you need to learn category theory, and if I were to put that mindset into a single sentence it would be: "It usually pays off to think about the structure created by the relationships between the objects that you're studying".  "Seven sketches" takes that attitude and runs with it, applying it to examples coming from chemistry, informatics, computer science, and so on.

It's also structured in such a way that you can get a broad feel for the subject without getting overwhelmed by the theory; the authors present a nice visualization of the difficulty of the book:

[image: 2]

Answer (score 9):

If you were like me at 17, you might be better served starting off with an introductory text on the language of mathematics itself.  I'd recommend the book "A transitition to advanced mathematics" available free [here](https://math.byu.edu/%7Epace/Transition_v102.pdf), or get an ereader version [here](https://math.byu.edu/%7Epace/Transition-ereader.pdf).

A list of other free math textbooks can be found [here](https://www.openculture.com/free-math-textbooks).

Answer (score 7):

You may want to take a look at [Applied Compositional Thinking for Engineers](https://applied-compositional-thinking.engineering) (ACT4E), an ongoing graduate course at ETH Zürich:

> In many domains of engineering it would be beneficial to **think explicitly about abstraction and compositionality**, to improve both the understanding of problems and the design of solutions. 
>  A kind of mathematics particularly well-suited for thinking about compositionality is **applied category theory**. However, at present, this mathematics is relatively inaccessible to the average engineer. This is due in part to the inertia of the education system: outside of computer engineering, only little algebra is taught, in favor of analysis and related fields. This made sense some decades ago, but does not reflect today's real-world needs. 
>  Recently, many good expositions of category theory for applications have appeared ([see resources](https://applied-compositional-thinking.engineering/resources)) yet to date, none are oriented explicitly toward engineering. This course will fill this gap. We will introduce the framework of monotone co-design as a means to teach basic concepts of category theory alongside principles of compositional engineering. Special care will be taken to illustrate the ideas with concrete examples (especially from autonomous robotics), and to indicate applications.

Answer (score 6):

A nice resource (a learning roadmap) for exploring introductory papers, books, and vids on category theory is Bradley's "[What is Category Theory Anyway](https://www.math3ma.com/blog/what-is-category-theory-anyway)?"

You like to see connections, so I would suggest, to provide a little focus yet an avenue for exploring diverse crossroads in math and physics (maybe even with some like-minded friends/schoolmates), that you try this challenge at a leisurely pace;

Given a real function $f(x)$ of a real variable represented as a power series about the origin that vanishes at the origin and its compositional inverse $f^{(-1)}(x)$, sketch the relationships among the two functions and the compositions $e^{t \; f(x)}$ and $e^{t \; f^{(-1)}(x)}$ elucidated by

1. category theory
2. Hopf algebra
3. differential geometry
4. geometric combinatorics
5. Lie theory
6. umbral / finite operator calculus
7. matrix algebra
8. statistical and classical mechanics.

I think you'll come to realize the strengths and shortcomings of the different approaches and how good Feynman's advice to constantly expand your bag of tricks / toolbox is.

Comment: Bradley's posts on category theory in reverse chronological order: https://www.math3ma.com/categories/category-theory

Comment: Another informative post: https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/discrete/category/index.htm

Comment: Historical development in the book Modern Algebra 
and the Rise of Mathematical Structures by Corry.

Comment: For me, category theorists can be a lot like group theorists--giving guidance when exploring the overall topography of a new field of research or extension, but not so much detail. E.g., I can define a set and an operation such as analytic functions $f(z)$ about the origin with $f(0)=1$ and reciprocation or $f$ with $f(0)=0$ and compositional inversion and say as an ardent group theorist, "Oh, those are 'just' examples of a group" then give the axioms of a group, but then the fascinating details that the first is related to permutahedra, the second, associahedra, are overlooked.

Answer (score 3):

Not trying to self-promote, but I have about 100 pages of [basic category theory notes](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/351884844_Category_Theory) I was planning on eventually pushing towards internal/two-dimensional category theory and putting on the arxiv as a survey article. They've been sitting around for two years now, though, so I uploaded them in their current (very unfinished) form in case they might help you. All the content on $1$-category theory is solid (sections 1-7), and sections 8-9 are serviceable, but please ignore the later sections for now.

They assume no familiarity with anything besides what a set and function are, although being familiar with the naturals/integers/rationals as distinct entities will help understand an early example of a non-surjective epimorphism. If you need to develop familiarity with sets please feel free to grab any standard text on set theory and read it, or if you like my notes you can try [this arxiv paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.08908.pdf) I uploaded a few years back which builds up the set theory you'll need from scratch. Again, the research at the end is shaky and shouldn't be used, but pages 1-6 give a 'from-scratch' development of the axioms of MK class theory and the stuff through page 19 offers some basic lemmas to try and prove (don't read my proofs unless you need to!)

Best of luck, and remember not to beat yourself up if things get challenging! The level of abstraction in either of the above note sets is likely to be a signifigant step up from the kinds of mathematics you've encountered thus far, so be sure to come back to [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com) and ask further questions! (MO is a bit too high level for this stuff generally speaking, as evidenced by the users trying to close the question, but these are completely reasonable questions over at MSE)

Comment: thank you so much, I just started reading your papers !

Comment: @MatiasT-C No problem, I'm glad they're of assistance :).

Comment: @AlecRhea I can't open the notebook.

Comment: @vitamind The service I used to upload it only gave me a month for free so the trial ended may 5th, but I'll upload them on researchgate today and update the link.